# C++: Duplicating a tree of derived elements

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion, deep-copy

I have a base class and several derived classes. The base class looks like this:

```
class Base
{
    int type; //the derived type the object belongs to
    int nOfChildren;
    Base** children; //each child can be any of the derived types
    ...
}
```

Now I need to duplicate an instance of `Base`. Because of the recursion, a virtual method `Base::duplicate()` is needed. It also seems clear what should go in it:

```
Base temp = new Base();
temp->type = temp;
temp->nOfChildren = nOfChildren;
temp->children = new Base*[nOfChildren];
```

beyond that, it's not so clear.

Do I allocate each `temp->children[i]` as a `Base` object or as a derived object? Do I need a case statement to cater to all possible derived types? Do I need to implement a `duplicate()` method for each derived type, even those that contain no other information than the Base class? (If a derived class contains more information, then it is clear that I need a separate mechanism. There are several derived classes that contain no further data than the base, although they contain different implementations of a `handler()` method not shown.)

Answer (score 4):

You are right, a virtual method is needed for cloning the polymorphic object. OTOH, you can leverage C++ features to simplify writing it:

```
class Child : public ICloneable {
public:
    // stuff...
    Child *clone() const { return new Child(*this); }
}
```

Also, don't put collections of objects into arrays! Use `std::vector` instead.

```
class Base
{
    // stuff...
    std::vector<Base*> children;
}
```

Even better, use a smart pointer to wrap the cloning operation into an object `std::vector` will be able to manage transparently.

```
template<typename T>
struct clone_ptr {
    T *object;

    clone_ptr() : object(new T()) {}
    clone_ptr(T *object_) : object(object_) {}
    clone_ptr(clone_ptr<T> const &other) : object(other.object->clone()) {}
    clone_ptr<T> &operator=(clone_ptr<T> other) {
        std::swap(object, other.object);
        return *this;
    }

    ~clone_ptr() { delete object; }
};
```

That way you can just use a `std::vector` of `clone_ptrs` into your Base:

```
class Base
{
    // stuff...
    std::vector<clone_ptr<Base>> children;
}
```

Each object will be automagically copied into an object of the same polymorphic type, as long as you implement clone() in each class. The vector will be cloned in the same way other data members are, automatically by the C++ compiler.

Comment: Need to check self-assignment in your `clone_ptr::operator=`, otherwise solid answer.

Comment: @Mr.kbok. "Also, don't put collections of objects into arrays! Use `std::vector` instead." I need to traverse these trees multiple times, and performance is a concern. With few exceptions I know ahead of time the number of children of each type of node. Is a <std::vector> competitive with an array under these circumstances?

Comment: @user3697176 yes, use std::vector to allocate the required buffer size up-front and avoid copies. Use emplace_back to construct object directly into the vector, and operator[] to bypass bounds checking

Comment: With optimizations enabled, std::vector used that way has the same performance as an array, with added safety and convenience.

Comment: @Barry: yeah, I was a bit quick to write that class :) I added safety for throwing clones since I'm at it.