# C++: Cloning and overloading with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, recursion, clone, multiple-inheritance

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396932/c-duplicating-a-tree-of-derived-elements). Someone asked about a minimal example, but I found it impossible to condense it all into something working. I still have issues, so I hope that by giving a bit more structure I can get some idea of what I am doing wrong or what I should be doing.

The classes I use form a tree structure, like this:

```
struct Base
{
      /* nodeType is a number uniquely assigned to each concrete class */
      int nodeType;

      int numberOfA;
      int numberOfB;
      int NumberOfC;
      int numberOfD;

      AdvancedA** A_array;
      AdvancedB** B_array;
      AdvancedC** C_array;

      Intermediate1** D_array; 

      virtual Base clone() = 0;
}  

struct Intermediate1 : Base
{
}

struct Intermediate2 : Base
{
}

struct Advanced_A : Intermediate1
{
      /* There might be different signatures since arguments might be
       * real-valued, complex, or even matrices
       */
      virtual double compute(signature 1); 
      virtual double compute(signature 2); 
}

struct Advanced_B : Intermediate1
{
      virtual std::complex compute(signature 1);
      virtual std::complex compute(signature 2);
}

struct Advanced_C : Intermediate2
{
      virtual matrix compute(signature 1);
      //for example; definition of matrix class is not shown 
}

struct Instance_A1 : Advanced_A
{
}

struct Instance_A2 : Advanced_A
{
}

...

struct Instance_B1 : Advanced_B
{
}

...

struct Instance_C1 : Advanced_C
{
}

...
```

I use these objects to build expression trees, which can evaluate to different types, corresponding to the three `Advanced` types. (Think of them as real-valued, complex-valued and matrix-valued expressions.) Because I need to evaluate the expressions, I have created three different types of expression trees, as follows.

```
struct BasicTree
{
      virtual void cloneTree();
}

struct TreeType_A : BasicTree
{
      Advanced_A* root;
}

struct TreeType_B : BasicTree
{
      Advanced_B* root;
}

struct TreeType_C : BasicTree
{
      Advanced_C* root;
}
```

I hope to eventually be able to use these in this manner:

```
TreeType_A* tree_A;
TreeType_B* tree_B;
TreeType_C* tree_C;

TreeType_A* copy_A;
TreeType_B* copy_B;
TreeType_C* copy_C;

copy_A = tree_A->cloneTree();
copy_B = tree_B->cloneTree();
copy_C = tree_C->cloneTree();

tree_A->root->compute(signature 1);
tree_B->root->compute(signature 1);
tree_C->root->compute(signature 2);
```

I have two concerns: The cloning of the array of `Advanced` elements will have to also clone the descendants. At the moment I put his into the method itself:

```
Base* Instance1::clone()
{
     Base* temp = new Instance1();
     (clone local stuff)

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfA; i++)
         temp->A_array[i] = this->A_array[i]->clone();

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfB; i++)
         temp->B_array[i] = this->B_array[i]->clone();

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfA; i++)
         temp->C_array[i] = this->C_array[i]->clone();

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfD; i++)
         temp->D_array[i] = this->D_array[i]->clone();
     return temp;
}
```

If possible I would actually prefer to write a method `cloneChildren` that takes care of the recursion transparently.

Mostly I want to avoid having to use explicit casting. Different instances of the `Advanced` classes have different content, and this content seems to get lost if I try to write, e.g.

```
         temp->A_array[i] = ((Advanced_A*)this->A_array[i])->clone();
```

On the other hand, using a long case statement based on the particular instance seems inefficient. So it seems I need to rely on automagic.

If further simplifications are possible, such as collapsing everything into a single tree type, or a single array of children, that would be great. (I doubt the former will work, because the `compute` functions need to look different and return different values for each type of root. The latter seems more promising to me.)

What other pitfalls might there be?

Comment: Why do use private inheritance?

Comment: @curiousguy "Why do use private inheritance?" As opposed to public inheritance? I did not show the "public" declarations to save space; as it is, the example is both woefully incomplete and overly long.

Comment: Another issue is that pointer can mean either indirection (one object) or array. Your code would be more readable with `vector` IMO.

Comment: OK. I think I have the `clone()`  methods figured out. But I am still not clear on the `compute()` methods. Suppose I have a `Base` class, several `Derived` classes, each with a virtual function `compute()`, several specific classes that derive from the various `Derived` classes and a container `std::vector<Base*> V`. How do I make sure that `V[i]->compute()` picks up the proper implementation?  Does it make a difference if the virtual functions have different names (i.e., `computeA()`, `computeB()`, etc.)?